# Mysql queries matching specific individual belonging to a group

Tags: mysql, database

So I'm just working on a project that needs to calculate the total price of each user's basket of products. I have the following tables:

```
users
+----+------------+-------+------------+
| id | group      | name  | bskt_price |
+----+------------+-------+------------+
|  1 | GroupA     | John  | 18.15      |
|  2 | GroupA     | Pierre| 12.45      |
|  3 | GroupB     | John  | 4.95       |

Items
+--------+-------+--------+------------+------------+
| item   | amount| price  | username   |group       |
+--------+-------+--------+------------+------------+
|  Pears | 11    | 1.65   | John       | GroupA     |
|  Apples| 3     | 3.6    | Pierre     | GroupA     |
|  Pears | 1     | 1.65   | Pierre     | GroupA     |
|  Pears | 3     | 1.65   | John       | GroupB     |


products_list
+------------+------------+
| item       | price      |
+------------+------------+
| Apples     |      3.6   |
| Pears      |     1.65   |
```

And I want to automatically calculate the bskt_price of each user when the prices in the product_list get updated. However, I don't want totals per user but per user in a group. Ie. I want to know the basket price of John in Group A, but not all Johns.

Before, I didn't have groups and it worked just fine with this trigger on products_list:

```
UPDATE users 
SET bskt_price = (SELECT basket FROM
   (SELECT name, SUM(i.amount*m.price) AS basket
   FROM users u JOIN items i ON u.name = i.username 
   JOIN products_list m ON i.item = m.item
   GROUP BY u.name) q1 WHERE q1.name = users.name)
```

The problem is now -as can be seen above- I have made every user belong to one or several groups and I can't make it work. I've tried something like:

```
SELECT name, group, SUM(i.amount*m.price) AS basket
```

But wouldn't work. I would appreciate your kind help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general approach to this problem seems right.  The trick in my mind would be to make sure that you are joining the tables in all of the appropriate places.  Try this query:

```
UPDATE users 
SET bskt_price = (SELECT basket FROM
   (SELECT u.group, name, SUM(i.amount*m.price) AS basket
   FROM users u 
   JOIN items i ON u.name = i.username AND u.group = i.group 
   JOIN products_list m ON i.item = m.item
   GROUP BY u.group, name) q1 
 WHERE q1.name = users.name AND q1.group = users.group)
```